# Open XML parsing a word as two words

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to parse a word document and extract few paragraphs. There is a document that I am not sure how/what the creator of the document did, it basically parsed a word as two words. For example, the word "standards", it is treating "st" as one word, and "andards" as another word.

Do you know if this is related to language, encoding, or anything else related to the document?

Here is how the section of the outerXml looks like:

```
-<w:r pt14:LanguageType="western" pt14:FontName="Calibri" pt14:StyleName="DefaultParagraphFont">
-<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorBidi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="" w:eastAsia="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:ascii="Calibri" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorHAnsi"/>
<w:b/>
<w:spacing w:val="-1"/>
<w:sz w:val="22"/>
<w:szCs w:val="22"/>
<w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:bidi="ar-SA"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>St</w:t>
</w:r>


-<w:r pt14:LanguageType="western" pt14:FontName="Calibri" pt14:StyleName="DefaultParagraphFont">
-<w:rPr>   
<w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorBidi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cs="" w:eastAsia="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:ascii="Calibri" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorHAnsi"/>
<w:b/>

<w:sz w:val="22"/>
<w:szCs w:val="22"/>
<w:lang w:val="en-US" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:bidi="ar-SA"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>andards</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: it isn't treating it as 2 separate words here, its just 2 separate runs that have different spacing properties.

Comment: Just as Daniel says... You'll find this quite often in Word documents - whenever any kind of formatting (including spelling language) changes. Sometimes it's something the user's done; sometimes, Word "autocorrects" things; sometimes, it's a total mystery...